# Space between labels when user leave a text field empty

Tags: iphone, objective-c

[image]

Hi 
I have some text field which, after a decoding, set some UILabel. The problem is that if the user leave some empty field , I don't like to see that space between the labels. I enclose a picture for a better understanding. thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you setting the label text? Can you paste the code snippet in the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of the view below use a uitableview with custom cells 
Each custom cell having a label ...and add a cell if and only if u have a valid string in a textfeild..set userinteraction=NO and set some backgroung color to match ur view..

just put that string in the uilabel in the custom cell...thats it..